# Are these algae responsible for concrete staining the same organism?

Tags: taxonomy, algae

I am interested in studying the effects of algae that cause concrete staining on the walls in my city, particularly because this green growth is widespread in my country, Quito, Ecuador.

[image: Green algae growth over walls]

Since I am considering establishing an in silico Genome-scale Metabolic Model (GEM), I need to determine whether this type of algae is a distinct organism or a composite of fungi, archaea, cyanobacteria, and other microorganisms.

I have some doubts, as I have successfully cultured a sample of this green algae using wastewater, NPK fertilizer, and exposure to sunlight. Moreover, these algae exhibit remarkable resilience to fluctuations in temperature and oxygen availability.

Comment: “ determine whether this type of algae is a distinct organism or a composite of fungi, archaea, cyanobacteria, and other microorganisms” have you tried using a microscope?

Comment: since its naturally occurring the answer will almost certainly be no, monoculture is a human invention.